# Correlating multiple readings from different sensors for the same variable

Tags: regression, time-series, correlation

I have three sensors measuring the same parameter. Of these, one sensor (D) is more accurate than the other two which are both of the same type (B). I want to use sensor B for my experiments and then use some correlation to get an estimate of what sensor D would've measured - something along the lines of

```
lm(D ~ B, data = experiment1)
```

I have time series data from one experiment during which all three sensors ran over the same time period (D, B1 and B2). Now since there would be two measurements for each measurement by sensor D (one from each B1 and B2), I'm not sure how to model that.

I'm not sure how to "mathematically" describe this problem but here's a some sample data (first six observations for each sensor).

```
                    tme         pm2.5 type
 1: 2017-10-01 21:00:00    1.09096000   B1
 2: 2017-10-01 21:00:59    1.09915000   B1
 3: 2017-10-01 21:02:00    2.45066000   B1
 4: 2017-10-01 21:02:59  858.76800000   B1
 5: 2017-10-01 21:04:00 2290.21000000   B1
 6: 2017-10-01 21:04:59 2285.36000000   B1
 7: 2017-10-01 21:00:00    0.00478904   B2
 8: 2017-10-01 21:00:59    0.01266030   B2
 9: 2017-10-01 21:02:00    0.01089970   B2
10: 2017-10-01 21:02:59  336.47300000   B2
11: 2017-10-01 21:03:58  924.33600000   B2
12: 2017-10-01 21:04:00  988.95300000   B2
13: 2017-10-01 21:00:29    4.00000000    D
14: 2017-10-01 21:00:59    4.00000000    D
15: 2017-10-01 21:01:29    4.00000000    D
16: 2017-10-01 21:01:59    4.00000000    D
17: 2017-10-01 21:02:29    4.00000000    D
18: 2017-10-01 21:02:59 1150.00000000    D
```

Comment: You have not indicated your goal. Do you want to check validity of instrument or else ? Which correlation    you want to compute . Append a summary of results.

Comment: So, there are two goals: To find out how the different sensors of type B (B1, B2, B3... Bn) measure the same quantity - in terms of repeatibility (or the like), variance etc. The second part if how to estimate the output of sensor D given the output of one general sensor of type B.

Comment: Please explain your data columns ?what is 2285 ? 1.09096 ? 1150??

Comment: Those are all readings of particulate matter (cumulative density of sub 2.5 micron particles) in sampled air. The test is set up to continuously vary the composition of air sampled by the sensors (dust, temperature, humidity, flow speed, flow profile etc.).